# OmniFaces @Param fails to use converter to set a primitive property

Tags: jsf, converters, cdi, omnifaces, param

```
@Inject @Param(converter = "#{pageConverter}") // or "pageConverter"
private int page;
```

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class PageConverter implements Converter
```

When using OmniFaces `@Param` on `page`, I get an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field com.example.Bean.page to null value
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:80)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:758)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:94)
    ...
```

My converter is supposed to take care of that, but `getAsObject` is never called.

This works:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="page" value="#{bean.page}">
        <f:converter binding="#{pageConverter}"/>
    </f:viewParam>
</f:metadata>
```

Comment: does your converter work if used in other ways?

Comment: Yes it does work when using view tag

Comment: Omnifaces version?

Comment: Does it work if you make it an Integer instead of int? Might be that int cannot be returned as an object, so maybe that is why the converter is not called at all.

Comment: @Kukeltje LATEST on maven. I tried with Integer and it didn't solve it. I think the int is auto boxed in Integer when return 0 is called. Do you personally use this feature? I believe the problem is that omnifaces simply doesn't find my converter

Comment: Well, the omnifaces source is open. Step-debug trough it... I'm currently looking into the 2.3 source if I see something

Comment: @Kukeltje No please don't do that for me.I was gonna use this out of convenience but I'm gonna use the meta data tag instead since it's inconvenient to debug. I got more important things to do than figure out a third party annotation. So please just forget it if you don't know the answer just by reading my post. I figured it might take someone who had the same issue 30 seconds to answer top.

Comment: :-) I'm curious as to why it does not work... did not find anything directly and won't try to replicate the coming weeks since I'm going on holiday

Comment: *"I tried with Integer and it didn't solve it."* It works for me. Perhaps you meant with "didn't solve it" that the converter is still not called? Exactly the same would happen with `<f:viewParam>`, so your statement is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is three-fold:

1. CDI doesn't natively support injecting primitive default values (customized producer needed).
2. `@Param` has never supported primitives in first place (because, poor practice).
3. JSF converters are never called when request parameter is entirely absent.

To solve 1 and 2, I have created [issue 266](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/266) and I will work on that before 2.4 final.

For now, just use `Integer` instead of `int`. It's also considered a better practice to not use primitives as model properties, because you can then use `null` to distinguish "value is never submitted" from "value is submitted, but is empty".

Moreover, JSF converters are never intented as "default value providers". The `<f:viewParam>` case would also never have triggered the converter when the request parameter is entirely absent. So that it "works" is actually not true. The effect of `0` being set is just result of EL coercion, which didn't involve the converter. Exactly the same problem is demonstrable when you entirely remove the converter from your case.

Comment: Thanks and I apologize for being a bit rude earlier

Comment: I just committed the fix, it's available in today's latest [2.4-SNAPSHOT](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/omnifaces/omnifaces/2.4-SNAPSHOT).

Comment: I finally had the chance to test it and it works. Any chance you upload it to maven though?

Comment: 2.4 final release is coming soon.